# How to edit a form in React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, react-redux

I tried to autofill the input field values. So, I sent the `id` via params from the `Cards` component to the `EditForm` component, and in `EditForm`, in its componentDidMount(), I used that `id` and fetched the post by id from the database, got the post from the store, and pulled out `title` and `description`. So, I made my form prefilled with values that I received from the store. Now, I'm stuck here. How do I edit this form? With these values that I have set in the `value` property of an input field, obviously I am unable to type anything because I wanted to make it prefill. Now, I'm thinking my approach was wrong. Please help.

`Cards`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react"

class Cards extends Component {

  handleEdit = _id => {
    this.props.history.push(`/post/edit/${_id}`)
  }

  render() {
    const { _id, title, description } = this.props.post
    return (
      <div className="card">
        <div className="card-content">
          <div className="media">
            <div className="media-left">
              <figure className="image is-48x48">
                <img
                  src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                  alt="Placeholder image"
                />
              </figure>
            </div>
            <div className="media-content" style={{ border: "1px grey" }}>
              <p className="title is-5">{title}</p>
              <p className="content">{description}</p>
              <button onClick={() => {this.handleEdit(_id)}} className="button is-success">
                Edit
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}


export default Cards
```

`EditForm`

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getPost } from "../actions/userActions"

class EditForm extends Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    this.props.dispatch(getPost(id))
  }


  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="title"
          value={this.props.post.post.title}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Title"
        />

        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="desctiption"
          value={this.props.post.post.description}
          className="textarea"
        ></textarea>

        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return store;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditForm)
```

Answer (score 0):

define 2 state title and description and set them after you pulled them. Then update the state via onchange function and pass the state as value to input and textarea

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say. Can you add some code in your answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { getPost } from "../actions/userActions"

class EditForm extends Component {
    constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      title: '',
      description: ''
    };
  componentDidMount() {
    const id = this.props.match.params.id
    this.props.dispatch(getPost(id))
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (nextProps.post !== this.props.post) {
      this.setState({
       title: nextProps.post.post.title,
        description: nextProps.post.post.description,
      });
    }
  }
  handleChange = event => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    })
  };

  render() {
    const { title, description } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="title"
          value={title}
          className="input"
          placeholder="Title"
        />

        <textarea
          onChange={this.handleChange}
          name="description"
          value={description}
          className="textarea"
        ></textarea>

        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = store => {
  return store;
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditForm)
```

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` has been deprecated.